# What happened to CacheStatisticsProvider in Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In **Spring Boot 1.x** we were using `CacheStatisticsProvider` (from org.springframework.boot.actuate.cache.CacheStatisticsProvider) in order to publish hitRatios of a cache via Rest.

In **Spring Boot 2** `CacheStatisticsProvider` is no longer available.
It got removed with the release of version `2.0.0.M4`.

In the release notes nothing is mentioned, but I suppose the removal has something to do with the switch to Micrometer.

How can I achieve the functionality described above with Spring Boot 2?

Comment: for me its actual question too